# How to define route

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

In my `routes.rb` file I've added member to movie resourses:

```
resources :movies do
  get 'search', :on => :member
end
```

So then I have this list of routes:

```
search_movie GET    /movies/:id/search(.:format) {:action=>"search", :controller=>"movies"}
      movies GET    /movies(.:format)            {:action=>"index", :controller=>"movies"}
             POST   /movies(.:format)            {:action=>"create", :controller=>"movies"}
   new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)        {:action=>"new", :controller=>"movies"}
  edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)   {:action=>"edit", :controller=>"movies"}
       movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"show", :controller=>"movies"}
             PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"update", :controller=>"movies"}
             DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)        {:action=>"destroy", :controller=>"movies"}
```

And I expected to use this route in my view as follows:

```
= link_to 'Find Movies With Same Director', search_path(@movie)
```

But it came up with error:

```
undefined local variable or method `search_path'
```

What is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function instead: `search_movie_path`

Comment: It was my silly mistake, by BTW I fixed your answer a little bit.